# append data to json file using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to append a username and password to a Json file. I have spent hours trawling this site and gone to lots of normally dependable tutorial sites (Derek Banas, The New Boston) for a definitive way to manipulate, append and parse a Json file and to my surprise I've not found one.

So I'm hoping someone maybe able to clear this up for me. So far I have managed to overwrite the data in my Json file, append data to the end but not in the form of an object. My Json file looks like this;

AJAX:

```
 {
 "LogIns":[
    {
        "Username":"Mike",
        "password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"Farrah",
        "password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"John",
        "password": "123"
    }

 ]
}
```

My HTML and AJAX looks like so:

HTML/AJAX:

```
<body>
<center>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please register before playing</legend>
        <form>
            Username: <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Username" id="username1" name="username"><br>
            Password: <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter a password" id="password" name="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return checkLogin();">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<div id="PHPid">

    <script>
        var usernamePassed = "";
        var userPassword = "";

        function checkLogin(){
            usernamePassed = document.getElementById("username1").value;
            userPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
            callAJAX();
            return false;

        }
        function callAJAX(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    //location.href="gameOption.html";
                    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("POST", "reg.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.send("username=" + usernamePassed + "&password="+ userPassword);
        }

    </script>
```

The PHP file looks like so:

```
<?php

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $str = file_get_contents('logins.json'); // Save contents of file into a variable
            $json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the data and set it to recieve data asynchronosly - store in $json
            array_push($data, array('Username' => $username, "password" => $password));
            file_put_contents('logins.json', json_encode($json));
?>
```

I'm trying to add data so that the next time someone registers it my Json file will look like this:

JSON;

```
{
"LogIns":[
    {
        "Username":"Mike",
        "password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"Farrah",
        "password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"John",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"Alfred",
        "password": "123"
    }

]
}
```

With the above code nothing is being printed to the console.

I have also tried this in my PHP:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $str = file_get_contents('logins.json'); // Save contents of file into a variable


            $json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the data and set it to recieve data asynchronosly - store in $json
            $data = array();
            array_push($data, array('Username' => $username, "password" => $password));

           file_put_contents('logins.json', json_encode($json));
```

Which also outputs nothing to the console but updates the Json file to look like the following:

```
{"LogIns":[
{"Username":"Mike",
"password":"123"},
{"Username":"Farrah",
"password":"123"},
{"Username":"John",
"password":"123"},
{"Username":"Alfred",
"password":"123"},
"Username:","mike",
"password:","123"
]
}
```

If someone could tell me that would be great, but also if they could clear up the way to overwrite the whole file, append an object inside a son file like above and also delete an object from a Json file it would be amazing!

I'm sure it's not difficult but I just can't seem to find a straight answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update the question to include your current json output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending in the wrong place.
You should append the new values to the inner 'LogIns` array, but instead you are appending to it's container.

```
<?php

$string = ' {
 "LogIns":[
    {
        "Username":"Mike","password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"Farrah","password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"John","password": "123"
    }
 ]
}';

$array = json_decode($string,true);

$extra = [
    'Username' => 'John',
    'password' => 'doe123'
];

$array['LogIns'][] = $extra;

print_r($array);
```

Will output nicely:

```
Array
(
    [LogIns] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Username] => Mike
                    [password] => 123
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Username] => Farrah
                    [password] => 123
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Username] => John
                    [password] => 123
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Username] => John
                    [password] => doe123
                )

        )

)
```

If you do a `json_encode` on the final array you will get the following

```
{
    "LogIns": [{
        "Username": "Mike",
        "password": "123"
    }, {
        "Username": "Farrah",
        "password": "123"
    }, {
        "Username": "John",
        "password": "123"
    }, {
        "Username": "John",
        "password": "doe123"
    }]
}
```

Also see the use of `[]=` instead of `array_push` which takes away the overhead of using a function.

Your next questions:

1. removing objects from a json objects
   Simply decode the initial json string into an array and operate on the array, remove items with `unset`,
   ex. `unset($array['LogIns'][2])` will remove the element with key 2
2. overwriting a file
   `file_put_contents` already does that, if you **do** want to append to the file instead you need to [pass the `FILE_APPEND` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for helping but that is overwriting all of the data in the JSON file not appending an object to the end of the file.

Comment: It now looks like: {"LogIns":[{"Username":"Alfred","password":"123"}]}

Comment: it shouldn't, see the `[]=` operator I used in my example which appends an element to the existing array

Comment: How do you mean sorry Alex? I just removed the empty [] so it now looks like: $array['LogIns'] = $extra; But that has just overwritten again so the file now looks like so: {"LogIns":{"Username":"Alfred","password":"123"}}

Comment: I'm sure your right and I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what

Comment: I also tried the FILE_APPEND but it added a whole new object like so:

Comment: {"LogIns":[{"Username":"Mike","password":"123"},{"Username":"Farrah","password":"123"},{"Username":"John","password":"123"}]}
{"LogIns":[{"Username":"Mike","password":"123"},{"Username":"Farrah","password":"123"},{"Username":"John","password":"123"},{"Username":"Alfred","password":"123"}]}

Comment: ok, leave the operator just like I used it, you are indeed overwriting the `LogIns` array if you remove it. The operator is a replacement for `array_push`, we are just replacing the use of a function with an array operator.  
Remove the `FILE_APPEND` flag if you **do not want** to append the new objects **at the end of the file** and just need the latest `json` in a file somewhere

Comment: in short `$array['LogIns'][] = $extra;` should stay as it is, this appends an element to the `LogIns` array

Comment: So I've changed it back to $array['LogIns'][] = $extra and this has been the output: {"LogIns":{"Username":"Alfred","password":"123","0":{"Username":"Alfred","password":"123"}}}

Comment: So unfortunately I'm still not getting my Json file to look like this: {
"LogIns":[
    {
        "Username":"Mike",
        "password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"Farrah",
        "password":"123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"John",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "Username":"Alfred",
        "password": "123"
    }

]
}

Comment: post your php code to eval.in or some other public paste service and send  me the link, I will take a look when I can.

Comment: I appreciate it Alex: I normally use phpcodechecker but have done it in eval.in, here's the link:  https://eval.in/558692

Comment: No it keeps appending to the file like so:                                            {"LogIns" :{ "Username":"Alfred","password":"123",                                      "0":{"Username":"Alfred","passwo‌​rd":"123"}}}

Comment: Instead of:  { "LogIns":[ { "Username":"Mike", "password":"123" },                   { "Username":"Alfred", "password": "123" } ] }

Comment: Hey Alex just seen this and went onto eval.in but nothing seems to have changed can you post your URL please? Thanks

Comment: Array ( [LogIns] => Array ( [Username] => Alfred [password] => 123 [0] => Array ( [Username] => Alfred [password] => 123 ) ) )

Comment: It seems your initial array is already malformed. Start again with empty file